# Removing custom cursor with js on touch devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a custom cursor on my site that I want to hide on touch devices (mobile/tablet). I have successfully done this but for a split second when you visit the website the cursor appears in the top left corner then is hidden. Is there any way to stop it displaying at all?

This is the code im using to remove the ID of the cursor on touch devices.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
{
    if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|Windows Phone/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    $('#custom-cursor').remove();
}
}
});
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
let cursor = document.querySelector('#custom-cursor');
document.addEventListener('mousemove', evt => {
    
  let { clientX: x, clientY: y } = evt;
  let scale = 1;
  
  if (evt.target.matches('a,span,[onclick],img,video,i')) {
    cursor.classList.add('active');
    scale = 0.5;
  } else {
    cursor.classList.remove('active');
  }
  
  cursor.style.transform = `translate(${x}px, ${y}px) scale(${scale})`;
  
});
});
```

```css
* {
  cursor: none;
}

#custom-cursor {
  position: fixed;
  width: 20px; height: 20px;
  top: -10px;
  left: -10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: #fb4d98;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 99999999;
  transition:
    transform ease-out 0.15s,
    border 0.5s,
    opacity 0.5s,
    background-color 0.5s;
}
#custom-cursor.active {
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: #000;
  border: 2px solid #fb4d98;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="custom-cursor"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing more of your code it's not possible to be absolutely sure, but from the info in the question it looks as though the whole page is loaded before the cursor is removed.

You could tackle this in a variety of ways, for example not having the cursor element in the initial HTML but adding it if required onload.

Alternatively you could leave your initial HTML as it is, but set the cursor to have display: none in your CSS. Then onload the JS adds setting the style.display to block if the cursor is not to be removed.

UPDATE: now having seen more of the code here is a snippet to show how the second method (cursor to have `display: none` until the page is loaded) might be implemented:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
let cursor = document.querySelector('#custom-cursor');

    if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|Windows Phone/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    $('#custom-cursor').remove();
}
else { cursor.style.display = 'block';}

document.addEventListener('mousemove', evt => {
    
  let { clientX: x, clientY: y } = evt;
  let scale = 1;
  
  if (evt.target.matches('a,span,[onclick],img,video,i')) {
    cursor.classList.add('active');
    scale = 0.5;
  } else {
    cursor.classList.remove('active');
  }
  
  cursor.style.transform = `translate(${x}px, ${y}px) scale(${scale})`;
  
});
});
```

```css
* {
  cursor: none;
}

#custom-cursor {
  position: fixed;
  width: 20px; height: 20px;
  top: -10px;
  left: -10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: #fb4d98;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 99999999;
  transition:
    transform ease-out 0.15s,
    border 0.5s,
    opacity 0.5s,
    background-color 0.5s;
    display: none;
}
#custom-cursor.active {
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: #000;
  border: 2px solid #fb4d98;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="custom-cursor"></div>
```

Comment: How would I implement the second way you mentioned? Ive added the full code to my question to make it easier for you to see whats going on.

Comment: I've put up a snippet.

Comment: Perfect thats working great, there is one final issue ive just noticed. Whenever you click through to a new page the cursor resets to the top left of the screen, then when you move the mouse it goes back to where you left the mouse on the screen, I need the cursor to stay where it is. I tried removing ` top: -10px;
  left: -10px;` from the CSS but it still resets to the top left, any idea why this is happening?